# How to cite a lecture note with the refer date and webpage?

Tags: bibtex, citing

I am referring a lecture note from [Andrew Sutherland](https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.783/2015/index.html), named [Elliptic Curves](https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.783/2015/lectures.html) provided on the related webpage.

I need to cite "14.Ordinary and supersingular curves" note, with the date which I refer the note and the link for the webpage, in my latex document using BibTeX. What is the most suitable Citation style and how I can type this in BibTeX file? I have used `alpha` style, but webpage links are not showing for that style.

Please recommend me a good reference style which support that too.

Comment: depends on your citation style. what are you supposed to use? APA? Havard?

Answer (score 6):

If a bibliography style (such as `alpha`) is sufficiently old so as not be be programmed to recognize and process a field called `url`, simply dump the URL-related information in the `note` field. I suggest you use the `@misc` entry type along with the `natbib` citation management package.

The following entry serves to refer to the totality of the lecture notes from the course in question. Make suitable adjustments if you want to create a reference to just one lecture.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{sutherland-notes,
  author = "Andrew Sutherland",
  title  = "{MIT Mathematics 18.783, Lecture Notes: Elliptic Curves}",
  note   = "URL: \url{https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.783/2015/lectures.html}. 
            Last visited on 2017/07/01",
  year   = 2015,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces]{url}
\usepackage{natbib}
\citestyle{alpha} 
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=cyan} % choose suitable colors

\begin{document}
\cite{sutherland-notes}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

If using biblatex and biber is an option (cf. [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13509/biblatex-in-a-nutshell-for-beginners) to get started), then I would recommend using the `booklet` or `report` entry types.

Per the documentation:

> ### booklet
>
> A book-like work without a formal publisher or sponsoring institution.
>   Use the field howpublished to supply publishing information in free
>   format, if applicable. The field type may be useful as well.
>
> **Required fields**: author/editor, title, year/date
>
> **Optional fields**: subtitle, titleaddon, language, howpublished, type, note, location, chapter, pages, pagetotal, addendum, pubstate, doi,
>   eprint, eprintclass, eprinttype, url, urldate
>
> ### report
>
> A technical report, research report, or white paper published by a
>   university or some other institution. Use the type field to specify
>   the type of report. The sponsoring institution goes in the institution
>   field.
>
> **Required fields**: author, title, type, institution, year/date
>
> *Optional fields*: subtitle, titleaddon, language, number, version, note, location, month, isrn, chapter, pages, pagetotal, addendum,
>   pubstate, doi, eprint, eprintclass, eprinttype, url, urldate

A possible example for your entry could be:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{sutherland-notes-misc,
  author = "Andrew Sutherland",
  title  = "{Elliptic Curves}",
  note   = "URL: \url{https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.783/2015/lectures.html}. 
            Last visited on 2017/07/01",
  year   = 2015,
}
@booklet{sutherland-notes-booklet,
  author = "Andrew Sutherland",
  title  = "{Elliptic Curves}",
  note   = "URL: \url{https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.783/2015/lectures.html}. 
            Last visited on 2017/07/01",
  year   = 2015,
}
@report{sutherland-notes-report,
  author = "Andrew Sutherland",
  title  = "{Elliptic Curves}",
  note   = "URL: \url{https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.783/2015/lectures.html}. 
            Last visited on 2017/07/01",
  year   = 2015,
  institution = "Massachusetts Institute of Technology, Department of Mathematics"
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{mybib}

\begin{document}
\cite[14. Ordinary and supersingular curve]{sutherland-notes-misc}, \cite[14. Ordinary and supersingular curve]{sutherland-notes-booklet}, \cite[14. Ordinary and supersingular curve]{sutherland-notes-report}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Note that the three entries will be displayed similarly:
[image]